# Hero box prompting me to sign up while logged in

Tags: bug, sign-up

I am currently being prompted to sign up while logged in. Removing the `{ "hero": "mini" }` cookie removes the call to action. I haven't re-logged recently (months?) though, so I'm not sure why that'd be generated now.

[image: signup while logged in]